# Right aligning cell content in a datatable column

Tags: css, jsf, datatable

I want to right align an outputText value (ie. fee.TableAmount below) and I want to keep the header for that column centered.  What parameter do I have to pass to outputText below to achieve this?

```
<h:dataTable>
    ...
    (other columns)
    ...
    <h:column headerClass="columnCenter">
        <f:facet id="header_agency" name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Amount"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{fee.tableAmount}">
            <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" groupingUsed="true"
                currencySymbol="$" type="currency" />
        </h:outputText>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `columnClasses` attribute of `<h:dataTable>` to specify CSS classes on all cells of the same column. You can pass a commaseparated string of class names.

```
<h:dataTable columnClasses="column1,column2,column3">
```

The above renders `<td class="column1">` for the first column, `<td class="column2">` for the second and so on. This allows you to externalize and normalize the styles.

Imagine that you have 4 columns and the first, second and fourth column doesn't need to have a special style and that only the third column needs to be right-aligned, then do so

```
<h:dataTable columnClasses="none,none,right,none">
```

in combination with

```
td.right {
    text-align: right;
}
```

which is semantically more correct and technically more robust than a `float: right;`.

Comment: True, but oddly enough for the `<thead><th>...</th></thead>` table headers it seems one can only specify the class [in `<h:column headerClass="...">` instead](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/column.html). So: CSS classes for column *data* are taken from `<h:dataTable columnClasses="..., ..., ..."/>` like described above, and the CSS for the column *headers* from each `<h:column headerClass="...">`.

Comment: @Arjan: The [`<h:dataTable>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/dataTable.html) has also a `headerClass` attribute. See also "Rendering the header" section of the aforelinked tag documentation.

Comment: Yes, but that applies to ALL column headers, and is not a comma-separated list for a specific class for a specific column, [is it](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/dataTable.html)?

Comment: Ah yes, I now see where you're coming at. Yes, the individual column headers have to be specified in the `headerClass` attribute of `<h:column>`. It would make sense if if there's a `<h:dataTable headerClasses>` and/or a `<h:column styleClass>`. Well, consider posting an enhancement request to JSF spec guys.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, if you define a `float: right` directly on your `<h:outputText>`, like this:

```
<h:outputText style="float: right;" value="#{fee.tableAmount}"/>
```

then it will nest your text in a `<span>` that will then be moved to the right.

Unfortunately, the `<h:column>` component does not provide a way to specify the CSS class of the column itself. However, in case you are using another component for your table, such as the Richfaces `<rich:column>`, there is another solution is to specify this: first, set a CSS class:

```
.textOnRight {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Then, assign this CSS class to your column:

```
<rich:column styleClass="textOnRight" headerClass="columnCenter">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Amount"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{fee.tableAmount}">
        <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" groupingUsed="true"
            currencySymbol="$" type="currency" />
    </h:outputText>
</rich:column>
```

By the way, setting an `id` in your `<f:facet>` does nothing, as this attribute is not handled by this component.

Answer (score 1):

I just added style="float:right" for anyone else wanting to know.

```
<h:outputText style="float:right" value="#{fee.tableAmount}">
   ...
</h:outputText>
```