# Setting width of all columns in dataTable

Tags: html, jsf-2, datatable, column-width

I am showing data in table format using `dataTable` in JSF page using JSF2.0. Below is the code that I have.

```
<h:dataTable id="patentBudgetList" var="patentBudgetList" value="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.budgetInfoList}"  border="1" width="40%">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Description" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{patentBudgetList.budgetTitle}"/>  
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Cost" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{patentBudgetList.budgetCost}"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

What I want is to set the width of `Description` column to `80%` and set  width of column `Cost` to `20%`.

Any idea how to get this done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112151/right-aligning-cell-content-in-a-datatable-column

Comment: Can you post your datatable options ?

Comment: @Ravi : How can you say it duplicate? how that link would help me??

Comment: @RicardoLohmann : Which option? I pasted dataTable code that I have...

Comment: You can make use of columnClasses to set the style for each column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is how I did...

```
<h:dataTable id="patentBudgetList" var="patentBudgetList" 
 value="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.budgetInfoList}"  
 border="1" width="40%"
 columnClasses="setWidthOfFirstColumn,setWidthOfSecondColumn"
>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Description" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{patentBudgetList.budgetTitle}"/>  
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Cost" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{patentBudgetList.budgetCost}"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

And in css I have

```
.setWidthOfFirstColumn {
    width: 80%;
}

.setWidthOfSecondColumn {
    width: 20%;
}
```